# Saving friend by admitting

Tags: witnesses

So, I would like to know what laws are there regarding the following scenario. Suppose that I commit some crime which unintentionally frames my friend. Let us say that I hack something but using my friend's PC and his internet connection without his knowledge. Now he gets caught but I am feeling guilty. So is it possible for me to claim that I had committed the crime without his knowledge and hence take the punishment on myself? Note that I would have no proof to assert myself, just my claim.

1. How would it vary if I am a relative instead of a friend?
2. How much would it depend on the country?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### A confession is not conclusive evidence

If all the evidence points to person A as the perpetrator and person B confesses unilaterally, person A is the one that’s going to be prosecuted. Because [I’m Brian of Nazareth](https://youtu.be/4SYc_flMnMQ).

Person A could try to have person B’s confession admitted as evidence, but every prosecutor worth their salt should get it ruled as inadmissible as having no relevance to the case against A.

Comment: a confession *alone*, but if you have specific knowledge that only the perpetrator could have that might tip the scales: for example telling exactly *how* you did it and *what* you did.

Comment: Let's say that instead it is something like posting something nasty against someone from my friend's account. Then there is a defamation suit. There is no way I would be able to save my friend right? Since there is no special knowledge required for the same

Comment: @UserNotFound defamation is a civil matter - you can give your friend the money to pay the damages if you want.

Comment: How is the confession not relevant?

Comment: Like this: the assassination of JFK, that was me. @GeorgeWhite

Comment: I thought you meant no confession can ever be relevant not that some confessions are ridiculous. " I killed JFK and this is exactly how I did it and how I framed Oswald", with corroborating information would be different.